# Why is my following XSL enters inside IF condition although expression is evaluated as false?

Tags: xslt

Could there be any reason for a XSL to enter into the scope even if the if condition is false? That's sounds like an absurd question but I cannot figure why this is happening for my following xsl-

```
<xsl:if test="count(../../TaskItems_Sheet/TaskItems[TaskReference=$taskRefMain and ../../TaskItems_Sheet/TaskItems/StartDate/text() = $varTaskStartDate] )>0">
   <ns0:TaskItem>
       <ns0:Add>
```

even though there is no task with matching both TaskReference & StartDate, it enters into the scope. The count is zero and the test expression is evaluated as false when I debug. Any idea about what I could've done wrong? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Please show a [minimal, verifiable code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For XSLT questions this includes at least a complete sample of the XML input and a complete XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: OK I'll need some time to get that, I need to modify names in the XML schema quite a bit to be able to publish that in public domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't confirm this without seeing more complete code samples, I think the logic in your current expression. It is not looking for a single `TaskItem` with matching both `TaskReference` and `StartDate`, but it is looking for a `TaskItem` matching `TaskReference` for which  there is another (possibly different) `TaskItem` that matches `StartDate`

I think your expression should be simplified to this

```
<xsl:if 
     test="count(../../TaskItems_Sheet/TaskItems[TaskReference=$taskRefMain and StartDate/text() = $varTaskStartDate]) > 0">
```

Comment: Spot on! That was indeed the issue I was having. Although my original question was a bit different but that(the solution you gave) is the actual problem I was having. THANKS A LOT! Splendid instinct I must say :)